# Text not Selectable on Flutter Web [Stable]

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

After the Flutter Web was Stable, i tried to convert my Flutter Mobile application to Flutter Web by following the instructions given in Docs.
Everything is good, but the problem here is the Text on the Web is not Selectable!
i have just converted a Flutter Mobile App to web by executing a couple of commands and don't have **any idea about Flutter Web or how it's Working Behind the Scenes!**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The web works with the same behaviour as your app, to make texts selectable, you wrap it in `SelectableText` widget.

For example:

```
SelectableText("Lorem ipsum...")
```

**Update for Flutter version >= 3.3**

A new widget `SelectionArea` has been introduced. The widget automatically makes its descendant Text widgets to be selectable.

For example:

```
SelectionArea(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          const Text(
            'Flutter',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 36, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 40),
          const Text(
            'Flutter version >= 3.3 Selectable texts',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          const Text(
            'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: const Text('Button'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
```

Comment: thankyou for the Quick response, it worked!

Comment: Isn't there a way of allowing all text to be selectable? Or should we add SelectableText everywhere?

Comment: So annoying having to do this everywhere...

Comment: With SelectableText it's impossible  to make a piece of text both selectable and clickable, so it cannot be used for links :(

Comment: What an unwise design decision from Flutter. I love the framework on mobile, but on the web it is far from being a good choice...

Answer (score 9):

There is a new widget `SelectionArea` in Flutter version 3.3. It allows selection of multiple text widgets inside of it.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SelectionArea-class.html